# SIGSTOP when trying to debug application in QTCreator running on an Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine through VirtualBox on Windows10

Tags: qt-creator, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to debug my C++ code in QtCreator (version 4.13.1 based on Qt 5.15.1) which is running on an Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine hosted on my Windows 10 using VirtualBox. As soon as I start the application in debug mode, I get the error:

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.
Signal name: SIGSTOP
```

I've tried changing the version of QtCreator, version of gdb I'm using to debug and tried with a few different versions of my code. The error only happens when debugging with the "Run in Terminal" option selected in the Project settings. The program runs normally if executed standalone in the gnome-terminal. Any idea for what might be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 19):

You should add the following 2 lines to Debugging Helper Customization:

- handle SIGSTOP nopass
- handle SIGSTOP nostop

*Tools->Options->Debugger->Locals & Expressions*

[image]

Comment: Wow - searched for two days until I came across this answer. Worked for me. Can you explain why?

Comment: Hi @derek, Unfortunately I can't say exactly what is causing this problem.I recently ran into this problem myself after upgrading packages. Going back to previous versions of the packages didn't help me in any way. There was no time to look deeper into the problem. So I just added these lines to the debugger settings so that it doesn't react to the SIGSTOP signal from the operating system.

Comment: Screenshot with solution is here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/100958/catching-unix-interrupt-signal-on-console-application-when-debugging-with-qtcreator